# Select/map each item of a Powershell array to a new array

Tags: powershell, higher-order-functions, array-map

I have an array of file names in Powershell, and I would like to prepend a path to each of them and get the result in a new array.

In C# I could do this using Linq...

```csharp
var files = new string[] { "file1.txt", "file2.txt" };
var path = @"c:\temp\";
var filesWithPath = files.Select(f => path + f).ToArray();
```

But what is the idiomatic way to do this in Powershell? It looks like there is a foreach syntax I could use, but I figure there must be a more concise, functional way to do it.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

An array in Powershell is declared with `@()` syntax. `%` is shorthand for `foreach-object`. Let's declare an array with all the file names and loop through it with foreach. `join-path` combines a path and a child path into a single path.

```
$files = @("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
$pFiles = $files | % {join-path "c:\temp" $_ }
$pFiles
```

Output:

```
c:\temp\file1.txt
c:\temp\file2.txt
```

NB: if the input consists of single an element, foreach will not return a collection. If an array is desired, either use explicit type or wrap the results. Like so,

```
[array]$pFiles = $files | % {join-path "c:\temp" $_ }
$pFiles = @($files | % {join-path "c:\temp" $_ })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't seen anything about that % shorthand.

Comment: This is good it looks like if the source array only has 1 element than the result will not be an array...is this your understanding?

Comment: @chosenbreed37 This is about four years old a question. Please post a new one, so that you'll get more attention from the community.

Comment: @vonPryz This question is the top Google result for _powershell map array_, and yours is the topvoted and accepted answer. If your suggested approach behaves differently when the input is of length 1 (and it seems that it does), then I think that's the kind of thing you should mention in your answer, not brush off to another question.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
$a = @("file1.txt","file2.txt")
$b = "c:\temp\"
$c = $a | % { $b + $_ }
```

I can't figure this w/o a foreach. Sorry

Using the great job from Josh Einstein [LINQ for Powershell](http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/linq-for-powershell)

you can write this:

```
$a = @("file1.txt","file2.txt")
$b = "c:\temp\"
$c = $a | Linq-Select -Selector {$b + $_ }
```

having same results in a LINQ manner but not using a foreach (`%`).

Comment: w/o `foreach` it will be `$c = $a | .{process{ $b + $_ }}`. It is basically the same but works faster.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin thank for this, never use this kind of 'foreach' ! Have you some percent value in faster excecution respect a %? thank you

Comment: This is very nice. I have never seen this syntax before. Can you please explain a little about the . in front of the {? Is this dot sourcing or something else?

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the replace operator:

```
PS> 'file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt' -replace '(^.+$)','C:\temp\$1'

C:\temp\file1.txt
C:\temp\file2.txt
C:\temp\file3.txt
```